# Can this constraint be cast as a second order cone constraint?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, convex-cone

Can someone please explain if it possible to convert the following constraint into a second order cone programming formulation:

$xy \ge ay + b$

Here $x,y$ are non negative decision variables, $a,b$ are two positive integer. I have plotted the feasible region in desmos and it looks pretty much convex.

I have been trying to manipulate the term using hyperbolic constraint but it seems to be the wrong way and at this point I do not know if it even possible to recast it.